# bug with force:navigateToURL in Salesforce1 when Salesforce1 Brand Color is customized

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

The built-in event works fine to open an external website, like below

```
//function in client-controller
videoOnCaseStudies : function(component, event, helper){
    var eventURL = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    eventURL.setParams({
        "url": 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOmL6ysIZrE'
    });
    eventURL.fire();
}
```

But I came across a case.There is a redundant bottom(green) on the new 'page', as shown below in screenshot. Is there any way to remove the bottom?

PS, Salesforce1 mobile native app

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just letting you know that I notified the appropriate people at Salesforce and this is getting fixed this week. I imagine (Safe Harbor) the next version of the hybrid client should have this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

With test, I'm almost positive that it's a bug in Salesforce1 when Salesforce1 Brand Color is customized to anther color as to default blue.
The bottom actually has some 'action links', but the 'action links' are missing when Salesforce1 Brand Color is customized to other color.

With default blue, see screenshot below.

[image: with default color blue]